# Linux : Signal : SIGUSR1 : Signal Handler : Measuring execution time?

Tags: c, linux, performance, signals, handler

I am using linux signals (specifically `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`) to send signal from kernel space (linux kernel module) to the user space (an application that uses the kernel module). These signals are handled properly and the functionality is working fine.

Now I want to measure the execution time of the signal handlers(preferably in nanoseconds or microseconds).

I have tried using `gprof` but it does not show the execution time of the signal handlers. Apart from this it shows the execution time in seconds.

I also tried using `Ftrace("nop" tracer, function_profile_enabled)` but that didn't work either.

How can one measure the execution time of the signal handler?

Comment: I believe you should not use signals for that.

Answer (score 1):

For user space programs, read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) then use [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) with `CLOCK_REALTIME` to measure time. Don't expect nanoseconds accuracy.

Read also carefully [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

I would not use signals for kernel <-> user-space communication. On Linux, I would suggest using [netlink(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) with [netlink(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/netlink.3.html) functions (or providing a device in your kernel module for that communication). You could have some event loop to handle these (e.g. with [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) ...)

See also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html); it has crude timing facilities for syscalls...

Comment: Thankyou! I am looking into your suggestions now. I will post my findings ASAP. Regarding using netlink instead of signals I will keep that in mind in future.

Comment: I agree: signals are not the best communication mechanism. Signals are not guaranteed to be delivered, for starters.